# Java multithreading with web sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, websocket, multiprocessing

I have a web application where the front end communicates with the backend through websockets. I want to multi thread each request coming from the front end. i.e; as soon as a socket request comes from the front end, I should create a separate thread for it so that it runs concurrently. I have a class that keeps track of each request and delegates the work to other class based on the request parameters. 
I want to multi thread the request processing. How should I start with it. I have knowledge about threads but I dont know the right approach to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is extremely bad. I can't stress how bad it is.

you should read about **asynchronous IO** and find a suitable Java library which supports (real) asynchronous Websockets.

A Thread per request is a recipe for server which can't handle more than few thousands request at a time. it was a popular approach back in the days, but ditched in favor of asynchronous IO + small threadpool.